# How to detect unplugged headphone jack in a UWP app?

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

Is there a way to get notified whenever a headphone jack is unplugged in a UWP app? I would like to do it without programming with low level APIs (i.e: WASAPI).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.phone.media.devices.audioroutingendpoint.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj662949.aspx

Comment: do you have any idea if can I do this in a background task?